# Style is not applied to TextBox in WPF

Tags: wpf, textbox, wpf-controls, styles

`HorizontalContentAlignment` is not applied to textbox....

Here is the style definition:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
 </Style>
```

and here is the TextBox definition

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <TabControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="tabControl1">
        <TabItem Header="TemplateItem">
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <GroupBox Header="Salutation" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0, 4, 0, 0">
                        <TextBox Name="tbSalut" Width="300"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="->" Margin="4, 0, 4, 0"/>
                        <TextBox Name="tbSalutTransl" Width="371"/>
                    </StackPanel>
```

Here is the full example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="10,1,1,1"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <TextBox Height="23" Margin="12,51,12,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

> `<Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>`

instead in style

Answer (score 2):

This

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
```

should be:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've tried it before, doesn't work either.

Also, I have added the full source code to the post.
Other properties work well for the TextBox.